# How to prevent calling of function on every postback request

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have bind complete menu on postback now every post back request function
    call and bind menu again i want to call it only first time please suggest
    here below is my code

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
objCommon = new Common();
Common.UpdateLoginSession();
if (hiddenMenuFlag.Value == "S")//used hidden field but not working as is
//does not retain value on post back please suggest
{
BindMenu("0");//here is function for binding menu
hiddenMenuFlag.Value="";
}
}
```

Comment: Where you are setting the hidden variable `hiddenMenuFlag`?

Comment: This is not MVC. Please correct your tags.

Comment: @user3779305 - And how `bindMenuFlag` is mapped with `hiddenMenuFlag`?

Comment: its an type error hidden field name  is hiddenMenuFlag

Comment: <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenMenuFlag" runat="server" Value="S" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 
if (!IsPostBack)
 {

--------------------------;
--------------------------;

}

All functions or code inside this condition will run only for the first time, when page is requested. It won't execute on reload.

If you want to run a code only once; when the user request the page then you can use some session as suggested above.

If you want to run a code only for the first time when application runs, then you can use Application state to control your code

Answer (score 1):

You could create a session variable and then check that variable to ensure your code will execute only once.

You create session variable like this:

```
Session["myVar"] = "myText";
```

And then you could check it value like below:

```
((string)Session["myVar"]) == "myText"
```